# Probabilistic method Kraft-McMillan inequality

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve as many problems as I can but I am a little confused on this one. It is in chapter 1, problem 9 (Probabilistic method, Alon & Spencer). The problem says

Let $F$ be a finite collection of binary string of finite lengths and assume that no two distinct concatenations of two finite sequences of codewords result in the same binary sequence. Let $N_i$ denote the number of string of length $i$ in $F$. Prove

$$\sum_i \frac{N_i}{2^i}\leq 1$$

The problem that I have is that I understand the problem as if $w_1w_2=w_3w_4$ then we must have $w_1=w_3$ and $w_2=w_4$, but if this is what they mean then let $F=\{1,0,100\}$ then the possible contatinations are: $11,00,10,01,1001,1100,0100,1000,100100$, so no two are the same, but then we would have $N_1=2,N_3=1$, so $N_1/2+N_3/2^3=2/2+1/8>1$. I assume I must be understanding the condition incorrectly.

Comment: It requires that no two distinct concatenations of two **finite sequences** result in the same sequence. So in your example you can concatenate $1$ and $0$ and $0$ to get $100$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered: As Quinn pointed out, the problem statement requires that no two distinct concatenations of two **finite sequences** result in the same sequence, so in your example you can concatenate $1$ and $0$ and $0$ to get $100$.

Comment: I guess I should've just answered thus. I didn't realize that was *all* the question was asking.

Comment: The wording of the problem seems strange, then. Why specify "no two concatenations of **two** finite sequences of codewords are equal" rather than the equivalent (right?) "no two finite sequences of codewords are equal"?

Comment: @Jack: No, that's doubly wrong. First, you misquoted; it doesn't say that the concatenations are equal; to the contrary, it says that they're distinct; they just result in the same binary sequence. Second, what you suggest instead means something completely different and is in fact tautological -- either "two finite sequences of codewords" implies, as it usually does, that they're two *different* sequences, then the statement is tautologically true; or it doesn't, then the statement is tautologically false.

Comment: @joriki Thank you. As an english learner I was a little confused by the wording of the problem. Now I can go ahead and try to solve it :)