# Kraft-McMillan inequality

Tags: combinatorics

Let $F$ be a finite collection of binary string of finite lengths and assume that no two distinct concatenations of two finite sequences of codewords result in the same binary sequence. Let $N_i$ denote the number of string of length $i$ in $F$. Prove

$$\sum_i \frac{N_i}{2^i}\leq 1$$

[Source: The probabilistic method, Alon and Spencer]

There is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383857/probabilistic-method-kraft-mcmillan-inequality) that clarifies the statement of the problem, but doesn't mention anything about how to solve the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the strings come from a non-binary alphabet source $\chi$, hence we can encode each symbol as $C(x)$, which is a binary sequence and $C$, is our encoder. we represent the length of $C(x)$ by $|C(x)|$. Hence we have for any $m>0$:

$(\sum_{x\in \chi}2^{-|C(x)|})^m=\sum_{u_1\in \chi}\sum_{u_2\in \chi}...\sum_{u_m\in \chi}2^{-|C(u_1)|}2^{-|C(u_2)|}...2^{-|C(u_m)|}=\sum_{u_1\in \chi}\sum_{u_2\in \chi}...\sum_{u_m\in \chi}2^{-|C(u_1)C(u_2)...C(u_m)|}$

Let $N_{max}=\max{(|C(x)|:x\in \chi)}$

then for any sequence $u_1u_2...u_m$ we have $|C(u_1)C(u_2)...C(u_m)|\leq mN_{max}$ in which $C(u_1)C(u_2)...C(u_m)$ is the concatenation of the binary sequences regarding to $u_1,u_2,...u_m$ respectively.

For any $1\leq i\leq mN_{max}$, let the $N_i$ be the number of sequences $u_1u_2...u_m$ such that $|C(u_1)C(u_2)...C(u_m)|=i$, then:

$(\sum_{x\in \chi}2^{-|C(x)|})^m=\sum_{i=1}^{mN_{max}}N_i2^{-i}$.

It is completely evident that $N_i\leq 2^i$, thus

$(\sum_{x\in \chi}2^{-|C(x)|})^m=\sum_{i=1}^{mN_{max}}N_i2^{-i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{mN_{max}}2^i2^{-i}=mN_{max}$

Hence $\sum_{x\in \chi}2^{-|C(x)|}\leq \sqrt[m]{mN_{max}}$

Now let $m\rightarrow \infty$, then we have:

$\sum_{x\in \chi}2^{-|C(x)|}\leq1$

This theorem is an important theorem in digital communication. Indeed when we want to examine a mapping from a non-binary alphabet to a binary sequence, is uniquely decodable, then one of the important touchstones is Kraft inequality

Comment: I don't understand it very well. How do you define your "non-binary alphabet source $\chi$, and what are the strings in there? Also, how is your encoder $C$ defined?

Comment: The non-binary alphabet $\chi$ is a set of symbols, which each symbols has its own probability of occurrence. For example this set can be a set like $\chi=\{1,2,3,4\}$. The encoder is a mapping from this set to a string of binary elements. For example consider the encoder $C$, in which $C(1)=00,C(2)=01,C(3)=10,C(4)=11$. In this example all the binary strings has the same length, but there is the possibility that the strings be of different lengths. So for example when we want to encode $124$, we map it to $C(1)C(2)C(4)=000111$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. However, I think you can't take $m\rightarrow\infty$, since you need to prove it for every $m$. (I agree that when you take $m\rightarrow\infty$, you get the result.)

Comment: There is only one restriction on $m$, and that is to be positive. Hence it is valid for all positive values $m$, so limitation is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But it seems the line 
$(\sum_{x\in \chi}2^{-|C(x)|})^m=\sum_{i=1}^{mN_{max}}N_i2^{-i}$ is not correct, because $N_i$ in the problem statement denotes the number of strings of length $i$ in $F$, not the number of strings of length $i$ which is a concatenation of $m$ strings in $F$.

Comment: No, it is correct. I will add further steps for more clarification after editing the response. You can see it after some minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18050/discussion-between-amir-and-simmons).